# GCP Cloud Functions with GPU access or Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have created a Google Cloud Function to do Image Processing, I am using a Deep Learning model for one part of the process, but It uses GPU so I could unable GPU to change CPU and it is working well. After reading many links.
My question is: how can enable use of GPU for Cloud Functions? How could I send one image to be processed in a Compute Engine instance with GPU from Cloud Functions? Finally, I read something about Atheros but it looks expensiver more than 1k/month.
Thanks for your comments and ideas.

Comment: Cloud Functions does not use GPU at all, just memory and CPU.  You should pick a different compute product if you need GPU.

Answer (score 1):

GPU are expensive, there is no real solution for that. You need to have a small VM with a small GPU to limit cost, but it's still expensive.

The communication between Cloud Functions and the VM is up to you. It can be through HTTP rest API, gRPC, custom protocol on custom port. If you use  the VM private IP, you need to add a [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to your Cloud Functions to bridge the serverless world managed by Google with your own VPC where live your VM

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any tutorial or documentation to do this connection?

Comment: To achieve which connection? Severless VPC connector is well documented on Google Cloud. If you want to expose API or something else, there is nothing specific to Google Cloud, it's generic programming

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did setup if a Virtual Machine and mounted flask, apache server to create my own api.